# htaccess redirect not working

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'd like to 301 redirect all `.com/language/X` URLs to `.com/members/?members_search=X`.

Test case:
`http://example.com/language/french` should 301 redirect to
`http://example.com/members/?members_search=french`

The rule I have set up:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/language/(.*)" "/members/?members_search=$1"
```

It works correctly when I use a `.htaccess` tester. The rule is at the very top of the `.htaccess` file. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Swap out "expertise" for "language" in the rule. It should be RedirectMatch 301 "^/language/(.*)" "/members/?members_search=$1

Comment: Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you've placed this rule at the top of the `.htaccess` file, `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive so still runs *after* other mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) directives, so you may have a conflict.

Try changing this to a mod_rewrite directive. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^language/(.*) /members/?members_search=$1 [R=301,L]
```

NB: No slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* when used inside `.htaccess` files.

You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: It's working! Thank you!