# htaccess redirect - replace special character

Tags: redirect, htaccess, regex

In my [previous post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/384352/htaccess-redirect-not-working), I asked about how to 301 redirect  all `.com/language/X` URLs to `.com/members/?members_search=X` using htaccess.

Thankfully I got help, and the solution was `RewriteRule ^language/(.*) /members/?members_search=$1 [R=301,L]`

I just discovered that I also need to convert any existing hyphens to spaces. I'm going to assume that there would be no more than 2 hyphens.

Test case

`http://example.com/language/american-english` should 301 redirect to `http://example.com/members/?members_search=american%20english`

It's fine if an extra redirect is added, for example,

`http://example.com/language/american-english` 301 redirect to `http://example.com/members/?members_search=american-english` which 301 redirects to `http://example.com/members/?members_search=american%20english`

Right under `RewriteRule ^language/(.*) /members/?members_search=$1 [R=301,L]`, I've added this code, which is incorrect:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} members_search`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ /$1\s$2 [L,R=301]`

Please let me know if any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, replacing your existing redirect (which is now the 2nd rule below):

```
# Repeatedly replace all hyphens with %20 - internally
RewriteRule ^language/(.*)-(.*) language/$1\%20$2 [N,DPI]

# Redirect to query string
RewriteRule ^language/(.*) /members/?members_search=$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

This achieves the hyphen replacement and redirect to query string in just 1 external redirect. No additional redirect is required. Any number of hyphens are replaced.

This needs to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file.

You will need to clear your browser cache. Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Additional notes:

- `language/$1\%20$2` - the `%` needs to be backslash-escaped, otherwise `%2` will be seen as an empty backreference, so you'd end up with `0` instead of `%20`.
- `[N,DPI`] - The `N` causes the rewrite engine to immediately start over - creating a loop until all hyphens are replaced. The `DPI` flag is required to discard the original path-info (ie. the part after `/language/` in the URL), otherwise this is re-appended (automatically) which could result in a rewrite loop.
- The `NE` flag is required on the second directive (the only change from your original rule) in order to prevent the `%20` being doubly encoded as `%2520`.

Comment: PERFECT. Thanks so much again for the solution + helpful notes.